# How to build Ionic App in Adobe Adobe Build?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic Framework is compatiable with Phone Gap but how can we build the ionic app in adobe build online.

Answer (score 0):

Download the ionic framework from their website, design your app locally (web development) and then upload your web assets - a ZIP file of your HTML, CSS and JavaScript to PhoneGap Build.

Comment: Did the same, but it says it is not a phonegap project. :(